# Software for daily report in work environment

Tags: reporting, microsoft-word

Currently I'm using MS Word 2013 for daily reporting in work place.

The data in report files is a combination of freeform text, tabular information, graphics, and so on. Report file contains lots of pictures and drawings.

We might use one single report file for each month.

The reports are meant for my boss. My boss doesn't prefer any special format, as long as he would be able to read them, and sometimes copy them to his own MS Word files.

The information in report files would eventually be archived for future reference.

I wonder if there is any software which is specialized for such daily reporting in the following ways:

- easier to edit,
- handle date periods automatically,
- stays fast when data increases,
- easier to share with people,
- archiving features,
- commenting/brainstorming features,
- cross-reference between different dates/contents easily,
- searchable easily (even among the photos if possible)
- to be able to inform people of modifications when a writer likes to inform others
- to be modifiable by several people at the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combinations of multiple tools provided my desired workflow:

- Clockify for daily report and time track.
- GitHub for coding, issues, pull requests, technical docs.
- JIRA for task management and agile sprints.
- Slack for virtual office and communication.
- Video calls for body-doubling and pair-programming.